# How to check if InputStream gets an empty and/ or null String?

Tags: java, null, stream

if I send a List Object to the Server via ObjectOutputStream which is null, then I got an exception.
So, I wanna check if the ObjectInputStream at server-side's is empty.
But I dont know how to do this.

neither ois.available() nor ois.readObject != null works.

Here is an example-code:
Client:

```
String str= null;//"Hello \n";


        //Nachricht mit AES verschlüsseln und an Server senden

        cipherAES.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, encryptionKey, iv);
         byte[] input = str.getBytes();
         byte[] ctLength = cipherAES.doFinal(input);

         List<Byte> messageToServer = new ArrayList<>();
         for(int i = 0; i < ctLength.length; i++){

             messageToServer.add(ctLength[i]);

         }
 //3. OUTPUTSTREAM#############################################################################  
         oos.writeObject(messageToServer);
        os.flush();
```

Server

```
//3.INPUTSTREAM#####################################################################         
       //ois.availale();At this place, it doesnt work. if List<Byte> isn't null result = 0;

       //Empfange Clients verschlüsselte Nachricht          
      List<Byte> encryptedMessageFromClient = (List<Byte>) ois.readObject();
     // At this place ois.available retruns the value of the Object, if the object isnt null;

   //#####################################################################
```

Comment: Your title has nothing  to do with your question. Your `InputStream` is an `ObjectInputStream`, and it is neither empty nor null. If your `List` is null when you sent it with `writeObject()`, it will be received as a null with `readObject()`, and you can test for that with `!= null`in the usual way. However it *isn't* null. It might be *empty*, but there is no apparent difficulty in handling that condition. There is no such method as `ObjectOutputStream.available()`, and it wouldn't be the answer if there was.

Comment: Your edit isn't much help. You aren't sending a string, so why is your title about strings? You could start by defining 'I got an exception'.

Comment: NB Do you understand that you can send the actual `byte[]` array? No need for the `List<Byte>` at all.

Comment: NB 2: 'At this place `ois.available()` returns the value of the `Object`, if the object isn't null' is complete and utter nonsense. It does no such thing. See the Javadoc.

Comment: In my example. its regardless of whether the string is null or the List<Byte>-Object is null, because if the string is null the Byte-Object is null, as well.
And the Inputstream requires an Object. If i define in my outputstream, that the outputstream sholdn't send an empty-object, the server throws still an exception, because the server requieres an inputstream.

Comment: This is all nonsense. 'It is regardless' refers to what?  If the plaintext string is null, you will get an NPE, and there won't be any `List`, or any `writeObject()`, and you need to code defensively against such errors, much earlier than anything shown here: why exactly would you be trying to encrypt and send a null string? The input stream does not 'require an Object'. Possibly you are unaware that any Java array *is* an Object.

Answer (score 0):

If you serialize List which contains null value with the help of writeObject() and try to deserialize it at server end you will get null again.

We don't have method as objectOutputStream.available() but we have objectInputStream.available() which returns the number of bytes that can be read without blocking.

Note that

ObjectOutputStream in Java can be used to convert an object to OutputStream. The process of converting object to stream is called serialization in java.

and

The Java ObjectInputStream class (java.io.ObjectInputStream) enables you to read Java objects from an InputStream instead of just raw bytes. You wrap an InputStream in a ObjectInputStream and then you can read objects from it. Of course the bytes read must represent a valid, serialized Java object. Otherwise reading objects will fail.

Comment: i mean ois.available() or ois.readObject() doesn't work in my case.
I have corrceted it in my topic.

Comment: @cd4user They work all right: they just don't do what you think they should do. It isn't the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Resolved. There is no patent remedy.
So, if you have several ObjectInputStreams, then work with "instanceof" or "!instanceof".

Please note: instanceof doesnt accept generic-objects.

Edit: Code-Example: Client:

```
    if (str != null){
        //Nachricht mit AES verschlüsseln und an Server senden

    cipherAES.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, encryptionKey, iv);
     byte[] input = str.getBytes();
     byte[] ctLength = cipherAES.doFinal(input);

     List<Byte> messageToServer = new ArrayList<>();
     for(int i = 0; i < ctLength.length; i++){

         messageToServer.add(ctLength[i]);

     }
      //3. 

    OUTPUTSTREAM##############################################
     oos.writeObject(messageToServer);
    os.flush();
       }
```

Code example Server:

```
             //3.INPUTSTREAM######################################

  Object readed = ois.readObject();

//##################################################
      if(!(readed instanceof requiredObject)){
           objectYouNeed = (cast_it)Object;
        }else
          {
            --> Go on with another Object which is in the stream
         }
```

Comment: 'intanceof' is not a solution to 'How to check if InputStream gets an empty and/ or null String?'